# how to kextunload AppleUSBCompostie on MacOSX for VirtualBox guest OS USB device working properly?

Tags: macos, usb, virtualbox

I had installed VirtualBox in Lion OSX, and found an USB device was not working properly in Window 7 guest OS. when I selected the USB device from VirtualBox devices menu to assign the USB device to guest OS, the VirtualBox report an error:

```
Failed to create a proxy device for the usb device
Error: VERR_OUT_OF_RESOURCES
```

I analyzed the output from kextstat and system.log,comparing the different between before and after the USB device insertion.

```
Oct 15 19:45:02 yee kernel[0]: 0        0 AppleUSBCDC: start - initDevice failed
Oct 15 19:45:02 yee kernel[0]: USBF:    26094.693   IOUSBCompositeDriver[0xffffff800bf6fb00](IOUSBDevice) GetFullConfigDescriptor(0) returned NULL
```

then I found there were two drivers loaded by Mac kernel

1) com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCDC

2) com.apple.driver.AppleUSBComposite

I can unload 1) using command "sudo kextunload -b", but can not unload 2). when I kextunload AppleUSBComposite

```
Kext user-space log filter changed from 0xff2 to 0xfff.
Kext kernel-space log filter changed from 0xff2 to 0xfff.
Requesting unload of com.apple.driver.AppleUSBComposite (with termnation of IOServices).
(kernel) User-space log flags changed from 0x0 to 0xfff.
(kernel) Received 'Unload' request from user space.
(kernel) Can't remove kext com.apple.driver.AppleUSBComposite; services failed to terminate - 0xdc008018.
Kernel error handling kext request - (libkern/kext) kext is in use or retained (cannot unload).
Failed to unload com.apple.driver.AppleUSBComposite - (libkern/kext) kext is in use or retained (cannot unload).
```

**how can I unload it for my guest OS USB device working properly!**